# Auto go back after clicking a link in Javascript

Tags: javascript

When a user click an href link with id="boo" I am trying to get the browser to automatically go 'back' after 2 seconds.

This isn't working and i'm reaching out for some help from you all. Thanks in advance!

```
document.getElementById("boo").addEventListener("click",
  function a(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {window.location = History.back},2000)}  
);
```

---

Edit: (Adding this to clarify my goal)
so basically i want to do two things on click. navigate to a different page (time.is) and then automatically go back to the original page after 4 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make the default function of `<a>` tag stop working. Please try adding `.preventDefault()`.

```
document.getElementById("boo").addEventListener("click",
  function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {window.history.back()}, 2000);
  }   
);
```

---

If you want to do two things on one click, I suggest this:

1. Open the other website in a new tab
2. Go back to a previous page after 2 seconds in an initial tab

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("boo").addEventListener("click",
  function (event) {
    // Remove .preventDefault()
    setTimeout(function() {window.history.back()}, 2000);
  }   
);
```

**HTML:**

```
<a id="boo" class="clock" href="https://time.is/" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: that does help. but i still want the <a> href link to work.  Do i need to move that action down to the JS?

Comment: What does 'work' mean? Do you need to move to the other website by clicking the `<a>` tag? I thought you wanted to go back to a previous page by clicking the `a` tag.

Comment: so basically i want to do two things on click. navigate to a different page (https://time.is) and then automatically go back a page in history after 4 seconds

Comment: but as per gere's comment i am see that once the new page loads we lose the JS from the first page... so its not possible to go back to the history.

Comment: I see. I'm sorry but I don't know how to do that. I recommend you add that explanation to your post.

Comment: Here's another solution. Check my post. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

A part from a syntax error (`history` should be lower case), you are setting window.location with the back function, without executing it.

This should fix your code:

```js
document.getElementById("boo").addEventListener("click",
  function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {window.history.back()}, 2000);
});
```

Comment: ty. i updated my code based off what you said but still nada. Going to share by jsfiddle link if you want to take a look. I'm still a noob at coding...https://jsfiddle.net/PinG1/081qgfj3/

Comment: The other answer is correct, since you are adding this event listener to an <a> element you need to preventDefault(), otherwise the browser will navigate to the linked page and you won't have any control more. Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m78tLzfe/4/ I added a console.log because history.back() will never work inside jsfiddle, but you can check in the console that the code is executed.